# how to return value inside of class in java

Tags: java, android

i'm a beginner in java, i try to make my 1st simple app that is allowing the user to interact with the app using voice but i have a problem on returning the result of speechRecognition. i have the following class:

```
class listener implements RecognitionListener{
   ....
   public void onResults(Bundle arg0){
      ArrayList<String> matches = arg0.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
          String result = matches.get(0);
   }
}
```

in this case i wanna get the value of

```
result
```

how can i get the value of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Listener implements RecognitionListener {

   ....

   public String onResults(Bundle arg0) {
      ArrayList<String> matches = arg0.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
      return matches.get(0);
   }

}
```

the above method definition works like so:

```
<access modifier> <return type> <method name>(<argument type> <argument name>)
```

Then the method can return a type of `<argument type>`

If the return type must be `void` then you can do something like this:

```
class Listener implements RecognitionListener {

    private String match = null;

    ....

    public void onResults(Bundle arg0) {
       ArrayList<String> matches = arg0.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
       this.match = matches.get(0);
    }

    /**
     * Get the match
     * can return null if onResults not called or matches.get(0) == null
     */
    public String getMatch() {
        return match;
    }

}
```

Comment: If an answer answers your problem sufficiently please accept it, otherwise tell us how to improve the answer to make it acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a class member and save your result in it:

```
class listener implements RecognitionListener{

String result; 

   public void onResults(Bundle arg0){
      ArrayList<String> matches = arg0.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
          result = matches.get(0);
   }
}
```

or just call another method of your class from within the onResult method:

```
class listener implements RecognitionListener{

String result; 

   public void onResults(Bundle arg0){
      ArrayList<String> matches = arg0.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
          doSomethingWithResult(matches.get(0));
   }
}
```